# How to skip a maven module and submodules by wild character

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build maven module which includes lot of submodules.
for e.g

```
module1
    - submodule1
    - submodule2
    - submodule3
    .....
module2
    - submodule21
    - submodule22
    ...
```

I can skip my modules by using -pl flag in command line.

```
mvn clean install -pl \!module1/submodule1
```

How to skip `module1` completely i.e. including submodules by wild character? Something like the following

```
mvn clean install -pl \!module1/*
```

Comment: **-pl !<module_name>** have you tried like this?

Comment: I have highlighted what i have tried. i am expecting all the submodules should be excluded using some wild characters

Comment: I usually temporarily edit the POMs to comment out the unwanted child modules in situations like that.  If you really want wildcard matching, I think you'll need a shell script.

Comment: @heenenee. Yes i can acheive it through shell script. But is there any flags available in mvn command in latest versions.?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: Why do you need to skip those modules? Can you explain that a little bit?

Comment: In the above scenario i want to exclude module1 and their submodules1,2,3. Now i have to give !module1/submodule1, !module/submodule2, !module1/submodule3. Instead, is there any option, such as !module1/* , which excludes all the submodules1,2,3.